# Circle Geometry - How to find Central Angle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

I am currently having issue with this Circle Geometry Problem:

[image]

As noted in the picture, I know that the two triangle are similar. However, I am unable to find the other two angles.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Alex

Comment: Do you happen to know any theorems involving angles and the circular arcs they subtend, by chance?

Comment: @EuYu Well, I know that the two triangles are similar as they subtend each other, but that's most of it.

Comment: The angles on the triangle look to be drawn by you, so do you actually know for a fact that the two lines are parallel to each other? If not, then the triangles are not similar.

Comment: The angles you have marked as congruent aren't necessarily.  They happen to look congruent, but you can't guarantee they are from the information given.  However: (1) A circular arc subtends the same angle from any vertex on the circle not in the arc.  Thus $y = 35$.  (2) A circular arc subtends twice the angle from a vertex at the center as it does from a vertex on the circumference (not in the arc).  Thus $x = 2y = 70$.

Comment: Can you prove that X = 2Y?  That should be a known theorem.

Answer (score 1):

There are no parallel  lines and so there are no similar triangles.

$y= 35^0$ (same angles in a circular segment)

and

$ x = 2 y = 2*35^0 =70^0$ (angle subtended at center is half that subtended at periphery.)

Comment: sorry, what I mean by that is the two triangle have the same angles.

Comment: Alternate angles can be  marked equal only when two lines are parallel. You assumed a parallelism when no parallels have been given to you in the problem.